# Which version of UBUNTU is suitable for my system config?

Tags: system-installation

Following is my system configuration

- Intel Dual Core processor
- 1 GB RAM
- 160 GB hard disk

Which version of UBUNTU will be suitable for me. I tried with `Ubuntu 14.10` which completely slow in my system.

Sorry am not sure about the tags either. Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: @karel - Not sure how it is duplicate. But can you tell me which version i can use. I didn't get anything from the duplicate answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu MATE 14.04, Xubuntu 14.04 or Lubuntu 14.04 Try them in that order, if the first lags, try the second, if the second lags, try the third, if the third lags, try the fourth. I think that **Ubuntu MATE 14.04** can be your choice.

Comment: @Helio - Thanks for the reply. Will try `Ubuntu MATE 14.04`

Comment: @Fireblade If you want to try Ubumtu MATE, better wait two weeks and try Ubuntu MATE 15.04 because 15.04 is the first officially supported by Ubuntu release of Ubuntu MATE and there should be a lot less problems with it. Don't want you to have to struggle with an unsupported distro if you are a new Ubuntu user.

Comment: I'd go with Xubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu Mate 14.04.

Comment: @karel: Ubuntu MATE 14.04 is LTS. I have is on my computer with zero troubles, however this is my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Ubuntu MATE 14.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/)

[image: Ubuntu MATE Screenshot]

Or [Xubuntu 14.04](https://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)

[image: Xubuntu Screenshot]